# PHP Form sending second email hours later

Tags: php, forms, email

I've got a PHP email form that is meant to send two emails - one to the person who filled out the form, and another to me and another person. It sends both emails just fine, but hours later it sent the emails again. I tested the form multiple times (5-10 minutes apart) and an hour later I got the second set of emails all together (as if its all waiting in some buffer and suddenly sends). This is the code I'm using:

```
// create email headers

$headers = "From: xxx@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: xxx@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$headers2 = "From: xxx@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Reply-To: xxx@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers2 .= "CC: yyy@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($email_from, "Your RSVP", $email_message, $headers);  
mail('xxx@gmail.com', 'RSVP Response from '.clean_string($name1), $email_message, $headers2);
```

Update: I checked my visitor log and it looks like there's another hit to the same rsvp.php page with the same parameters filled out (which is whats resending the email) some time later. I made sure I closed the page immediately after submitting the form. The IP address of the second hit doesn't match the first (though both are accurately mapped to my location and ISP).

Comment: Nothing in this code would send duplicate emails. If anything, it would be a server configuration (or misconfiguration) sending it or another process that is setup to explicitly do this. `mail` by itself wouldn't.

Comment: Unfortunately my expertise is really just front-end, could you point me to where I might find that issue? The website itself is EXTREMELY simple, it's just my wedding website.